# PHP preg_replace all except a specific string

Tags: php, regex

In the string:

`$text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';`

How can I preg_replace all except "fox"?

Something like:

```
$new = preg_replace('(.*?)|^[fox]|(.*?)si', '', $text);
```

Note:
I'm looking for a preg_replace() solution, not explode() or preg_match_all().

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `preg_replace` is not the right choice for this. Simply match the path/filenames instead.

Comment: Yes that could be helpful.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: I know - I was trying to make it as simple as possible.. disregard the query - how to replace all but string with nothing? Let me try to rephrase the question.... again.

Answer (score 1):

Not I well understand your need, but how about:

```
$new = preg_replace('/^.*?(fox).*?$/si', '$1', $text);
```

Comment: Can it work for multiple "fox" on different lines? It does work for example (thank you), but need it to catch every instance (was in original question before edit). Is that the lightest regex wise? Will accept as answer if all the foxes are caught. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to grab the `path/whatever` as you pointed.

```
(path\/[^\[\]\s]+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sO6hX9/1)***

[image]

What I'm not clear about is related to your output string since you put:

```
"path/file1.txtpath/file2.jpg[/imgpath/file3 to a [i"
```

My regex would help you to generate:

```
"path/file1.txtpath/file2.jpgpath/file3"
```

Can you confirm is above is ok?

Comment: @user3925824 lol thanks for be willing to give +1. In my answer I provided with a link named [Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sO6hX9/1) you can check it the example working

Comment: @user3925824 I see, can you put what is the output you want?

Comment: hard to read with escaped slashes `\/` and the OP already had chosen another delimiter `*` (not great either) so no need to escape them, also no need to escape `[` inside a char class and no need to escape `]` outside one

Comment: @CS I'm asking for help writing it, that's why it's "not great". duh lol - Fede had a solution. You've posted no solution. Can you help, or only critique?

Comment: To note, Fede's solution was using preg_match_all which isn't what I'm looking for in this instance - although +1 for trying.